# Does my current version of Ubuntu already have an iso file. If so where do I find it to copy to a USB so I can upgrade

Tags: upgrade, usb

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 (and then incrementally to later versions) but I can't find the iso file which I need to copy to a flash drive before I can download 18.04. Once found, how do I copy it?

Comment: Why do you need an iso file for upgrading? Which version do you have now? Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).

Comment: If you want to upgrade to a current release you can do it without any iso file with the command `do-release-upgrade`, but must do it stepwise between LTS versions. If you want to install from an iso file, you should [get the iso file of the version and community flavour you want](https://releases.ubuntu.com/), for example 20.04.3 LTS (now the latest and greatest LTS point version).

Comment: The ISO file is used to install a system, not upgrade it.

Comment: please edit the version you are running now into your question.if you are running an intermediate version like 15.04/10 or 17.04/10 it might be advisable to do a clean install of a LTS from an ISO.

Comment: In an Ubuntu tutorial it tells me that with a bootable USB stick I can either upgrade or install a new version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy any ISO file to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu. There are plenty of online tutorials on how you can perform an upgrade: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start

If you want to do a clean install of the newest version of Ubuntu, then you'll need an ISO file on a USB drive, but you don't need to copy one from your current system - just download the newest version's ISO from Ubuntu's website.

Comment: an iso file burned to a DVD works just as well